# Show copilot inline suggestion together with "regular" auto completion list in vscode

Tags: visual-studio-code, github-copilot

[Case1: with inline no autocompletion list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1LICq.png)

[Case2: with autocompletion list no lineline](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8ZaTK.png)

As in the images, when Vscode triggers "regular" auto suggestion list, it disables the copilot's inline suggestion. Any way we can keep both?

Btw, [Nvim has both](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y8st1.png)

Comment: did you manage to find a solution for this? I'm facing the same issue

Comment: Same issue. It'd be great to have a solution.

Comment: I've got the same issue. Gets very annoying